# Android java round a double to turn it into int

Tags: java, android, int, double, rounding

I have to following code that returns me a double sum result.
I want to round it as follow 
if the result is from 0 to 999 i want it to round up into next 10 eg 956.5 to round it to 960.
If the result is from 1000 to 4999 i want it to round up into next 50 eg 1116.5 to round it to 1150.
If the result is from 5000 to anything i want it to round up into next 1000 eg 10116.5 to round it to 11000.

My code is

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String f = et1.getText().toString();
    double i = Double.parseDouble(f);
    String s = et2.getText().toString();
    double j = Double.parseDouble(s);
    String w = et4.getText().toString();
    double q = Double.parseDouble(w);
    double price_gold = 10;
    double fpa = 10;
    double fpol = 10;
    double fpolam = 10000;
    double isot = 10;
    double sint_ker = 10;
    double result1 = (i * price_gold) + (j * 1000) + (q * isot);
    double result2 = result1 / 340.75;

    if (result2 >= fpolam){
        double result = result2 * 1.10;
        String res = String.valueOf(result);
        et3.setText(res);
    } else{
        double result = result2;
        String res = String.valueOf(result);
        et3.setText(res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't checked if zozelfelfo code does the trick to your issue. But you asked about how you can implement this to your code. Due to that i haven't got enough Reputation to comment, i Need to put an answere.

Regarding to your issue:

Simply put zozelfelfo's code into a method:

```
private int calculate(double numberToCalculate) {
    double gap;

    if(numberToCalculate < 1000)
    {
        gap = 10;       
    }
    else if(numberToCalculate < 5000)
    {
        gap = 50;
    }
    else //5000+
    {
        gap = 1000;
    }

    int my_result = Math.ceil((numberToCalculate / gap)) * gap;
    return my_result;
```

After that you can call this from your onClick-Method like:

```
int myNewNumber = calculate(your number which you want to calculate);
```

If you are completely familiar with methods and i'm just telling you something you already know, then i'm sorry. Just wanted to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do so using the following:

```
double gap;

if(result < 1000)
{
  gap = 10;       
}
else if(result < 5000)
{
  gap = 50;
}
else //5000+
{
  gap = 1000;
}

int my_result = Math.ceil((result / gap)) * gap;
```

That should do the trick :)

Comment: seems to be ok the way you send but how i can embed this code to mine?

Comment: which variable is the one which you want to round to int?

Comment: Dont get it why I do not have even +1 when I gave you the correct algorithm :\

Comment: @zozelfelfo i don't get why someone downvoted my answere which helped him implement your code..that's what he wanted to after you put your code.. strange world..

Answer (score 0):

and the final code

```
int gap;
            if (result2 >= fpolam){
                double result = result2 * 1.10;

                if(result < 1000)
                {
                  gap = 10;       
                }
                else if(result < 5000)
                {
                  gap = 50;
                }
                else //5000+
                {
                  gap = 100;
                }
                int total = (int) Math.ceil(result2 / gap) * gap;




                String res = String.valueOf(total);
                et3.setText(res);
            } else{

            }
```